# iTextSharp: C# image to PDF - Spread big asp chart on more than one page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a very tall asp chart(PNG file), let's say 4000px in height. When the pdf file is generated using iTextSharp, it has only one page and i can see only 25-30% of my chart. I don't want to scale the image to fit into one page. I want to spread/split my chart on multiple pages so I can see the chart's details. If my chart fits into four pages, the PDF also needs to have four pages.
In the image bellow you can see my chart, how I want it (spread on 6 pages), and how it actualy looks generated by iTextSharp (the top of the chart displayed on one single page).
[Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bccsb80hit9qaoi/itextsharp.JPG)

```
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Chart1.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        iTextSharp.text.Image chartImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream.GetBuffer());
        chartImage.ScalePercent(70f);// This solves the width of the chart
        pdfDoc.Add(chartImage);
        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Chart.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a document with A4 pages in landscape. That means that you can scale the width of your image to 842pt, so instead of using `ScalePercent(70f)`, you could use `ScaleToFit(842f, 100000f);`

Note that I'm choosing `100000f` for the height as an arbitrary high number. I'm only interested in the width because you want to fit the image on A4 pages.

Once you've scaled the image, you need to know the scaled height: `chartImage.ScaledHeight;`

Suppose this height is `h`. Then you need to divide `h` by 595. That's the height of your pages. Unless `h` is an exact multiple of 595, ou will need `(h / 595) + 1` pages to show the complete chart.

Suppose this value is `p` (the number of pages that are necessary). In that case, you need to create a loop from 1 to p, and add the same image and trigger a new page over and over again.

However: before adding the image, you need to change its absolute position: `chartImage.setAbsolutePostion(0, (p - i) * 595);`

I don't know how to write C# (I'm a Java developer, actually the original developer of iText), but I'm sure you can cook yourself an example with this info.

Answer (score 5):

This solution saved my day, thanks to Bruno.

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Chart1.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        iTextSharp.text.Image chartImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream.GetBuffer());
        chartImage.ScaleToFit(822f, 10000f); // 822 instead of 842 because I have 20f padding (10 + 10) at first line            
        int pageNbr = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Truncate(chartImage.ScaledHeight / 595));
        int p = 0;

        if (chartImage.ScaledHeight % 595 == 0)
            p = pageNbr;
        else
            p = pageNbr + 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++)
        {
            pdfDoc.NewPage();
            chartImage.SetAbsolutePosition(10, -(p-i)*595);
            pdfDoc.Add(chartImage);

        }
        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Chart.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```